# Dependências na mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Uma funerária me pediu para fazer um simples esquema de cadastro de clientes pra eles.

Um cliente pode ter vários dependentes que usufruem do seu plano contratado caso este venha a óbito. Estou em dúvida quanto ao modelo de dados. Eu poderia criar duas tabelas, sendo uma para os clientes e um para dependentes, fazendo uma relação 1:N, mas não acho que seria sensato pelo fato de a estrutura das tabelas ser a mesma.

Poderia também criar uma única tabela com um campo `boolean`, para verificar se um cliente é dependente ou não. Mas e se ele for dependente? Como vou relacionar ele com outro presente na mesma tabela? Em MongoDB acho que isso seria simples, mas aqui estamos falando de MySQL.

Se ambas as abordagens forem indecentes, alguém poderia me sugerir uma melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Auto relacionamento

Quando preciso fazer este tipo de AutoRelacionamento crio um campo, como no seu caso, **TitularId** que se for nulo, é o titular, senão este é o dependente do titular referenciado

```
ClienteId | Nome     | CPF         | TitularId
  1       | Pedro    | XXXXXXXXXX  | NULL
  2       | João     | YYYYYYYYYY  | 1
```

Esta estrutura é ótima para se criar registros em árvores, onde o registro filho conhece o seu pai, e o pai pode ter muitos filhos e seus filhos serem pais de outros registros como:

```
+ Home
- Assuntos
  - Desenvolvimento
    - C#
      - MVC
      - WCF
      - WebApi
    - Delphi
    - Java
      - J2EE
      - J2SE
- Outros
```

### Tabela de vinculação

Outra form e ter uma tabela de vinculação, com ambos os campos chaves referenciando uma tabela de clientes, talvez até com um campo para identificar o contrato, visto que um dependente também pode fazer um plano para si

```
TitularId  |  DependenteId
-----------------------------
  1        |    2
  1        |    3
  4        |    5
```

Que é ótima para casos de relacionamentos N para N como:

```
Projetos
-----------------
|Id  |  Nome     |
|-----------------
| 1  |  FrontEnd |
| 2  |  BackEnd  |

Usuarios
-----------------
|Id  | Nome      |
|-----------------
| 1  |  AAAAAA   |
| 2  |  BBBBBB   |
| 3  |  CCCCCC   |

|UsuariosProjetos
|------------------------
|IdProjeto |  IdUsuario |
|------------------------
|1         |     1      |
|1         |     2      |
|2         |     1      |
|2         |     3      |
```

### Tabela de Contratos (Vinculação do Contrato ao Dependente ao invés de CLiente/Dependente)

Você pode fazer a tabela de cliente não ter de se preocupar com esta regra. Tanto o Titular quanto o dependente são **Clientes**

sendo assim você poderia ter uma tabela de contratos:

```
ContratoId  |  ClienteId | DataInicio | DataFim
  1         |     1      | 01/01/2001 | NULL
```

e uma tabela de dependentes

```
ContratoId | DependenteId
  1        |    2
  1        |    3
```

### Concluindo

No seu caso, recomendo a utilização do modelo de Vinculação ou de Contrato, dado que pode ser que um dependente seja dependente de mais de um cliente, e que um cliente em um contrato pode ser dependente em outros

### Exemplo

Senhor B e Senhora A
Filhos C, D, E

A senhora A faz um plano e coloca o marido e os filhos como dependentes A -> B,C,D,E
O Senhor B faz outro plano e coloca a esposa e filhos como dependentes B -> A,C,D,E

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
  ClienteId INT NOT NULL,
  Nome VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (ClienteId)
);

CREATE TABLE contratos (
  ContratoID Integer NOT NULL,
  ClienteId Integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (ContratoID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ClienteId) REFERENCES clientes(ClienteId)
);

CREATE TABLE dependentes (
  ContratoId INT,
  DependenteId INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ContratoId, DependenteId),
  FOREIGN KEY (ContratoId) REFERENCES contratos(ContratoId),
  FOREIGN KEY (DependenteId) REFERENCES clientes(ClienteId)
); 

INSERT INTO clientes (ClienteId, nome) VALUES (1, 'A');
INSERT INTO clientes (ClienteId, nome) VALUES (2, 'B');
INSERT INTO clientes (ClienteId, nome) VALUES (3, 'C');
INSERT INTO clientes (ClienteId, nome) VALUES (4, 'D');
INSERT INTO clientes (ClienteId, nome) VALUES (5, 'E');

INSERT INTO Contratos (ContratoId, ClienteId) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO dependentes (ContratoId, DependenteId) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO dependentes (ContratoId, DependenteId) VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO dependentes (ContratoId, DependenteId) VALUES (1,4);
INSERT INTO dependentes (ContratoId, DependenteId) VALUES (1,5);

INSERT INTO Contratos (ContratoId, ClienteId) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO dependentes (ContratoId, DependenteId) VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO dependentes (ContratoId, DependenteId) VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO dependentes (ContratoId, DependenteId) VALUES (2,4);
INSERT INTO dependentes (ContratoId, DependenteId) VALUES (2,5);
```

Comment: Neste último caso, ambos os campos seriam chaves estrangeiras?

Comment: Sim, seriam dois campos PFK (Primary Foreign Key)

Comment: Aqui no MySQL Workbench ficou assim:

http://imageshack.com/a/img829/1425/z025.png

Está certo?

Comment: @PedroVinícius Criei um exemplo no [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c70bd/3)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um auto-relacionamento em sua tabela, veja no exemplo abaixo:

[image: Auto-relacionamento]

Neste caso, para titulares você deixa o campo `id_titular` como `null`.

Para selecionar os titulares e dependentes:

```
SELECT 
a.nome as titular,
b.nome as dependente
FROM cliente a
LEFT JOIN cliente b
ON a.id = b.id_titular

WHERE a.id_titular IS NULL
```

Neste caso o a cláusula `WHERE` é para selecionar todos os clientes e dependentes.

Se quiser selecionar um cliente específico e seus dependentes, altere a cláusula para

```
WHERE a.id = 1 //id do cliente titular
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09b15b/11)**